# Do MySQL can do automatic EXPLAIN on every query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

We only have two Junior DBAs, no Senior DBAs, no one to guide us. We need to review each and every query for almost 30 large projects.  Each query took between 5 minutes and two hours depending on the query. As a reviewer, it was a real drag on my time.

My question is, do MySQL can do automatic EXPLAIN on each query, without having to run EXPLAIN by hand and log the result of un-optimized queries? Or maybe by cronjob? If possible, how to do this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to "review each and every query"? What's involved in that review?

Comment: Use `pt-query-digest` to tell you the "worst" queries (from slowlog).  Focus on those.

Comment: What is your response when using MySQL Command Prompt to SELECT @@VERSION;

Answer (score 2):

Enable MySQL's Slow Query log.
Anything that takes more than the defined time will get written into that log and you can take a look at it.

Or, better still, throw it back at the Developer that wrote the query and get *them* to take a look at it and then then write a *better* query.

"Teach a man to fish ..." and all that ...

Databases are *everybody's* responsibility, **not** just the DBA's.

Comment: If you are using Percona's 5.7, see https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/diagnostics/slow_extended.html#log_slow_verbosity for how to get the `EXPLAIN` automatically.